# Where does Gradle store downloaded jars on the local file system

Tags: gradle

How does Gradle store downloaded jar files on the local file system? Maven stores them in the `.m2` directory under `USER_HOME`, but where does Gradle store them? I checked the `.gradle` folder there, but saw only compiled scripts.

Answer (score 272, accepted):

Gradle caches artifacts in `USER_HOME/.gradle` folder. The compiled scripts are usually in the `.gradle` folder in your project folder.

If you can't find the cache, maybe it's because you have not cached any artifacts yet. You can always see where Gradle has cached artifacts with a simple script:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:12.0'
}

task showMeCache doLast() {
    configurations.compileClasspath.each { println it }
}
```

Now if you run `gradle showMeCache` it should download the dependencies into the cache and print the full path.

Comment: On my Mac for Gradle 2.4, it (currently) is in `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1`.

Comment: the left shift operator `<<` is being deprecated on Gradle 3.2 http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2016/11/gradle-goodness-replacing-operator-for.html

Comment: The left shift operator is deprecated but still works (as of Gradle 4.10). It's going to continue to work until Gradle 5

Comment: How to declare `compileClasspath` ?

Answer (score 438):

On Mac, Linux and Windows i.e. on all 3 of the major platforms, Gradle stores dependencies at:

```
~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1
```

Comment: `cd %userprofile%\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1` — a short command to locate to this directory on Windows.

Comment: Is there any logical reason why  `modules-2\files-2.1` ?

Answer (score 55):

In Windows 10 PC, it is saved at:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\
```

Comment: Can I force change that path to some other location?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28927173/192373

Answer (score 23):

Gradle's local repository folder is:

- $USER_HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1

Defined dependencies will be loaded from remote repositories into gradle's local repository folder. For each loaded file, gradle will be create a new folder named with md5 value of the original file (pom,jar,..). Full path for the dependency file is made up from :

- groupid + artifactid + version + **FILE_MD5_VALUE** + FILE_NAME

If our defined dependency is:

- compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.3.4.RELEASE'

Then the library will be loaded into :

- /$USER_HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.3.4.RELEASE/**42175d194cf6aa7c716c0887f30255e5c0a5262c**/spring-jdbc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar

Comment: MD5 is deprecated now it uses SHA1 value

Comment: Afterwards FILE_HASH_VALUE was been more generic .Thanks for your comment alphaguy.

Answer (score 23):

In fact the cache location depends on the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` environment variable value.
By default, it is `$USER_HOME/.gradle` on Unix-OS based and `%userprofile%.\gradle` on Windows.
But if you set this variable, the cache directory would be located from this path.

And whatever the case, you should dig into `caches\modules-2\files-2.1` to find the dependencies.

Answer (score 16):

If you want your dependency files to be in some specific folder you can simply use a `copy` task for it. For Eg.

```
task copyDepJars(type: Copy) {
  from configurations.compile
  into 'C:\\Users\\athakur\\Desktop\\lib'
}
```

Comment: Your task prints NO-SOURCE in console, and don't copy dependencies!!

Answer (score 8):

I am on windows,

You should be able find the dependencies inside

$USER_HOME.gradle\caches\artifacts-24\filestore

Comment: On my Mac for Gradle 2.4, it (currently) is in `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1`.

Comment: I use windows 10 and it is saved under: C:\Users\[user]\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1

Answer (score 6):

Many answers are correct!
I want to add that you can easily find your download location with

```
gradle --info build
```

like described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54000767/4471199.

New downloaded artifacts will be shown in stdout:

```
Downloading https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-parent/2.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-parent-2.1.7.RELEASE.pom to /tmp/gradle_download551283009937119777bin
```

In this case, I used the docker image `gradle:5.6.2-jdk12`. 
As you can see, the docker container uses `/tmp` as download location.

Answer (score 3):

In android studio do the following steps to check the gradle downloaded jar file.

1. Set project structure view to "Project"
2. At bottom External library section available, expand it.
3. Here you can see downloaded jar files.
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the gradle argument `--project-cache-dir "/Users/whatever/.gradle/"` to force the gradle cache directory.

In this way you can be darn sure you know what directory is being used (as well as create different caches for different projects)

Answer (score 3):

I just stumbled onto this while searching for this answer. If you are using intellij, you can navigate to the file location, but opening the external lib folder in the project explorer, right clicking on the jar, and select Open Library Settings. [image]

Answer (score 2):

It took me a while to realize this, hence the additional answer. Hopefully it can save folks time. Note that if you are running `sudo gradle` the dependencies may not be in your home directory, even if `sudo echo $HOME` returns `/Users/<my-non-root-user>/`. On my Mac, Gradle was caching the dependencies in `/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/`.

Answer (score 1):

In case it is an Android gradle project - you can find the android libraries below your $ANDROID_HOME/extras/android/m2repository folder

Answer (score 1):

On my windows machine with "Buildship 2.0.2" plugin installed in eclipse, dependencies are stored :

$USER_HOME.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I was using an Ivy repository, and my Gradle dependencies were stored in `~/.ivy2/`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Mac. Go to the home of your directory,  where you have press cmd +shift + period to show didden file. Click on .gradle , click on wrapper, then on dist,here we go

Answer (score 0):

Here is the document.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/directory_layout.html

> By default, the Gradle User Home (~/.gradle or C:\Users<USERNAME>.gradle) stores global configuration properties, initialization scripts, caches, and log files.

According to this document, the downloaded dependencies are stored at (~/.gradle or C:\Users<USERNAME>.gradle ) caches/modules-2