# How to copy all dependencies to Maven Repository through Gradle?

Tags: maven, dependencies, gradle

I am building my project using gradle, But gradle only copies the artifacts to local maven repository, not all the dependencies.
What i need is to copy artifacts along with their all dependencies into local maven repository.

Please suggest a way to do it in gradle.
I tries gradle's documentation but in vain.

Comment: Try adding resolved artifacts to artifacts - archives. However using maven local with gradle isn't the best practice.

Comment: Could you explain why do you want dependencies to be in local Maven? If you are using Maven script anywhere, the script will pull the dependencies into local Maven. You will end up with two copies, but it is ok, since you are using two build tools.

Comment: I am using Karaf environment & karaf works with maven repository. So to install my packages i need to refer to maven repository.

Comment: If i cannot copy the dependencies to Maven repository then can i refer gradle repository from karaf.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible, gradle store dependencies in [local cache](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/cache_dependencies_into_local_maven_repository_from_gradle).

Only [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834111/gradle-store-on-local-file-system) if it fits for You is resolve dependencies and copy to some defined folder (but it's not possible to use it later from maven ) so probably will not help for You.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem with you.
So I start a python project to clone the dependency into my local maven.
Through it's not pure gradle, but it work.

https://github.com/Jintin/syndle

You can try this out.

Simply install by `pip3 install syndle`.