# How to set gradle cache location?

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I see the following info in Eclipse package explorer:

[image]

Is it possible to change this location?

Answer (score 67):

Globally you can set

> [...] Gradle user home directory (defined by the “GRADLE_USER_HOME” environment variable, which [...] defaults to USER_HOME/.gradle) [...]

See also https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties.

Otherwise for every build manually:

> -g, --gradle-user-home
>   Specifies the Gradle user home directory. The default is the .gradle directory in the user's home directory.

See https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html.

Comment: The first link isn't working anymore. Information about the Gradle user home directory can be found here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties

Comment: I have a user home -- May I also put the Caches some place else like a `tmp` drive?

Comment: Note: If you're running `gradle` or `./gradlew` commands in a CI/CD pipeline, using a `yml` file, you must use `export GRADLE_USER_HOME="/path/to/folder"` . The `export` command is important, to ensure that the environment variable is available to all scripts and sub-scripts that Gradle uses.

Comment: finally a normal answer, for all projects I hope it will work

Comment: it is strange why the issue https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1319 is still open.

Answer (score 15):

You can change the cache location since gradle 3.5. This is controlled in **settings.gradle** file for your project:

```
buildCache {
    local {
        // Set local build cache directory.
        directory = "${settingsDir}/build-cache"
    }
}
```

*[thanks to Hubert Klein Ikkink, a.k.a. mrhaki](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2017/04/gradle-goodness-change-local-build.html)*.

Comment: why build-cache? here says ".gradle": https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#antivirus-impact

Comment: This cache location is controlled by the script, for specific project. I chose to name this directory `build-cache`, you are free to use name `the-best-directory-in-town`. Only be careful if the path has spaces, some tools may misbehave.

Comment: This answer conflates the *build cache* and the *dependency cache*.
This question is about the *dependency cache*, which is where dependencies are stored locally when resolved.
However, this answer is about the *build cache* which is where build outputs are stored and is usually disabled unless it's [explicitly been enabled](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html#sec:build_cache_enable).

Comment: this is for one project. the question - for all projects automatically use specified gradle cache path? what you answered I can with Android Studio interface, no need to configure gradle. but Studio also sets it for the project only

Answer (score 5):

You can change the location of gradle cache location in eclipse by setting the eclipse gradle preference

In Eclipse open,  window-> preferences
Search for 'Gradle'
set 'Gradle User Home' to your preferred location
Click Apply/ok

Now for the changes to take effect, you might have to do Gradle-> Refresh Gradle Project

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was to edit my Windows environment variables and add variable GRADLE_USER_HOME with value `d:/.gradle`. (Replace "d:/.gradle" with the path to your gradle home.) Then exit and restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the location of the cache specifically, but you can change the Gradle user home directory (the .gradle directory) which the cache is located in by using the `-g` command line argument.

Comment: Yes you can, see http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2017/04/gradle-goodness-change-local-build.html