# Is it safe to delete the %USER_HOME%/.gradle and %USER_HOME%/.AndroidStudio3.1 folder in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

These two folders take up significant space on my hard disk

- `%USER_HOME%/.gradle`
- `%USER_HOME%/.AndroidStudio3.1`

Can they be safely deleted? If not, what subfolders can I safely delete?

Answer (score 13):

Well, it's "safe" in that it won't blow up your computer. But the `.gradle` folder is a dependency cache - every library your app needs is going to need to be stored there in order for you to actually build / test / run your code. It's to be expected that it'll take up a lot of space. You might get some mileage out of deleting it and re-downloading the dependencies, especially if there are a lot of old dependencies in there that you're not using it, but by virtue of your work it's going to get re-created and start filling back up again.

The Android Studio folder is a bit similar - it's not a dependency cache in that lots of different things aren't going to get installed there, but it's still necessary for you to actually build your code. If you delete it you're just going to have to reinstall things there to get your code to work.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply sir
is ther any  methot to keep all thos folder in the same as android studio becose i use a external drive to be able to move it whit me anyu were a go

Comment: @DavidP.Swanson refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28838699/how-to-set-gradle-cache-location - you can indeed set the gradle directory. I'd recommend against setting it as the _same_ directory, but you can definitely set both of them to sit on your external drive if you want.