# Error building android project with gradle using teamcity

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, teamcity

Using team city to build and android app. keep getting an error.

> [16:59:38]    [Step 1/1] Execution failed for task
>   ':app:mergeDebugResources'. org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource
>   compilation failed Output: 
>   C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\3467ebf6f9d1bb66db4bdb226db55512\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png:
>   error: file not found.
>
> Command:
>   C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\8a1ce91548f2547bb27874a553d3981d\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe
>   compile --no-crunch \
>           --legacy \
>           -o \
>           C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\7028d0f31da34ed0\Workshop\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug
>   \
>           C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\3467ebf6f9d1bb66db4bdb226db55512\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png
>   Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #1

The file it says it can't find is definitely there. I'm a .net developer with hardly any experience of android development so I have no idea what to look at next in order to fix this. please help.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the file, which seems to be an image, and adding it back to the project? Maybe it is an issue of references.

Comment: do you have this image abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha .png in your drawable-hdpi-v4?? @user1450877

Comment: Clean the project and Run, the file which is showing is coming from v4 libs.

Comment: I don't have a drawable-hdpi-v4 folder as part of my project. but the folder and file does exist on the path the error message shows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AAPT2 still seems to have some trouble with long paths on Windows. Try moving your gradle cache closer to `C:\` to shorten the file path.

Here's an answer on how to change the cache location: [How to set gradle cache location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28838699/how-to-set-gradle-cache-location)