# gradle.user.home - set in gradle.properties, build.gradle, or settings.gradle to a project-relative location?

Tags: gradle

By default, `gradle.user.home` is set to `~/.gradle` - I'd like to change it to a directory relative to the project, rather than the developer's home directory.

I know you can do so when you invoke gradle, like so:

```
$ gradle --gradle-user-home=./project-relative-directory
```

Or

```
$ gradle -Dgradle.user.home=./project-relative-directory
```

I know you can [change the location of the build cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55381607/622192) by adding the following to settings.gradle:

```
buildCache {
    local {
        // Set local build cache directory.
        directory = "${settingsDir}/build-cache"
    }
}
```

But gradle continues to use `gradle.user.home` for other caching.

The [manual](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html) claims that you can specify `gradle.user.home` in `gradle.properties`, like so:

```
systemProp.gradle.user.home=./project-relative-directory
```

But this doesn't appear to work at all, not for absolute paths or relative paths; although it may be retrieved later via `System.get`, `gradle` doesn't appear to make use of it.

Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Gradle parses `gradle.properties` file, too much has already happened. So the only way to use a custom Gradle home is through a command line flag, which has the highest precedence, or through a system property.

Note that [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_system_properties) indicates that and does not mention the ability to set that value inside a properties file.

Comment: I won't argue with the correctness of the answer, but the link only seems to say "gradle.user.home=(path to directory) Specify the Gradle user home directory", which suggests that the user may in fact set the user home directory.

Answer (score 6):

you can also do it by changing the GRADLE_USER_HOME env variable. In this case all files will be saved in the specified directory.

```
export GRADLE_USER_HOME=./project-relative-directory
```