# How to set custom path for .gradle directory for android build in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, path

I want to use custom path for `.gradle` folder instead of `$USER_HOME/.gradle` because i am already developing android apps and changed this path to custom path from which it does not affect if whenever i install new windows so i can save me from downloading all that files and different version of gradle wrapper again and again so when now i start learning flutter i realize that its always creating that folder in my `$USER_HOME/.gradle` directory and there is no option in flutter to change this behavior and i also tried to open the android folder of flutter project from android studio and try to change the path from there but this doesn't help either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update 1 - Easy way for windows

set environment

- Set `GRADLE_USER_HOME` as `D:\gradle\.gradle`

---

Solution for this is to add this line `set GRADLE_USER_HOME=(D:\android\.gradle or your custom path) // remove that brackets` in `android\gradlew.bat` file at the first line and that's it now you can use your old gradle download files

Comment: Editing gradlew.bat file is not a good practice since it is a wrapper file and when you upgrade your Gradle wrapper this change would not be retained. Instead, create a `gradle.properties` file in the project's root directory and set a system property `gradle.user.home=(path to directory)`. See [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_system_properties)

Comment: can you please elaborate your comment further because when I use `gradle.user.home=D:\\android\\.gradle` in `gradle.properties` it's not working its creating `.gradle` directory in the default directory of user home

Comment: Do you have any other gradle.properties file defined on the command line or in the .gradle directory in user's home directory. If so, `gradle.user.home` property set in those property files will override the value in gradle.properties in project directory. See [how gradle properties file picks up the values](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties) from Gradle documentation.

Comment: The GRADLE_USER_HOME can also be got when you enable the debug flag. E.g., `gradlew <task> --debug`

Comment: no, I haven't defined any file even I have deleted the default `.gradle` folder from my home directory or probably I am not setting the path format correctly but I have searched this should be a valid format in windows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56350799/gradle-user-home-set-in-gradle-properties-build-gradle-or-settings-gradle-to check this post to to know more on this problem